# How to create a single file vue to handle rendering through table rows

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to be able to do something like this where we render the pricings sub-header and the detail rows. It's part of an html table. But this doesn't run. I can't wrap in a template tag. How should I handle this?

```
<template>
  <tr v-if="pricings.length > 0">
    <td colspan='2'>{{type_phrase}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="pricing in pricings">
    <td>{{pricing.name}}</td>
    <td>{{pricing.value}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-else>
    <td colspan='2'>No {{type_phrase}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  props:['pricings', 'type_phrase']
}
```

I can't wrap in a template or div. What's the general strategy for this?

Comment: Templates need a single root element. A `<tbody>` would probably serve here.

Comment: thx  - not sure if you're supposed to have multiple tbodys but works great! thx

Comment: Multiple tbody tags [are allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) (see "usage notes") -- the only catch is that if you use any `<tbody>` in a table you must enclose all the `<tr>`s in a `<tbody>`